# Web Browser will not navigate to link

Tags: c#, winforms

My `WebBrowser` object will not `Navigate()` to the link I give it.
The object remains empty when I run it.

When I put the url into the url property though, it successfully loads the link.

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webbMain.Navigate("https://twitter.com/login");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

You can try the following in Page_Load:

```
WebBrowser wbbMain= new WebBrowser();
wbbMain.AllowNavigation = true;
wbbMain.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Also, you can try to provide override for DocumentCompleted event.

If nothing works, then see if Internet explorer is isntalled. If its not installed then web brower may not work.